# PathSeparator is not rendering in asp menu control

Tags: asp.net, aspmenu

PathSeparator is not rendering in asp menu control, below is my code

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" PathSeparator=">" StaticDisplayLevels="10">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="About Us"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>        
</asp:Menu>
```

am I missing anything here? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: is it the `>` or any path seperator which is not shown?

Comment: @Fender if I give any character as path separator, it won't display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is by design: the value of the [PathSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.pathseparator.aspx) property is not supposed to be rendered on the page.

Its only purpose is to specify the separator character to use in the [ValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.valuepath.aspx) property.